# ansible - include the static script file in roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Below is my directory structure for ansibel role called webserver

localhost roles # tree

```
.
├── readme.md
├── site.yml
└── webserver
    ├── files
    │   ├── createswap.sh
    │   └── nginxkeyadd.sh
    ├── handlers
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── tasks
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── templates
    │   ├── helloworld.conf.j2
    │   └── index.html.j2
    └── vars
        └── main.yml
```

my tasks/main.yml looks like

```
- name: Create swap file 50MB
  script: /etc/ansible/roles/webserver/files/createswap.sh
- name: add GPG key for nginx
  script: /etc/ansible/roles/webserver/files/nginxkeyadd.sh 
- name: Install nginx on target
  apt: name={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items:
   - rsync
   - git
   - nginx
```

in the task/main.yml im specifying absolute path to local scriptfile like

`script: /etc/ansible/roles/webserver/files/nginxkeyadd.sh` and `script: /etc/ansible/roles/webserver/files/createswap.sh` . The scripts don't have any ansible variables.
is it good practice in ansible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it good practice in ansible ?

No. Excerpt from the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html):

> Any copy, script, template or include tasks (in the role) can reference files in roles/x/{files,templates,tasks}/ (dir depends on task) without having to path them relatively or absolutely

Also using shell-scripts instead of native Ansible modules is an antipattern.